# Global warming: change in Earth's potential energy

Tags: thermodynamics, newtonian-gravity, atmospheric-science, estimation

It is quite common to hear in newspapers and television about the increasing temperature, i.e. global warming.

But I am interested in something else.

How does global warming affect the internal energy of the earth, or else how does this change the gravitational potential energy of a point mass and the earth?

This is a open question and everyone should feel free to make any plausible assumptions in estimating the increase or decrease.

I thought of global warming as causing the expansion of the atmosphere, possibly changing mass distribution of Earth's atmosphere.

Comment: I believe most of the energy content goes into the oceans, so just use the heat capacity of water to compute the energy increase, and $E=mc^2$ to compute the corresponding mass increase, and then Newton's law of gravitation for the change in potential etc.

Comment: Hi navinstudent. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an interesting question. No one seems to adress this anywhere. 
We know that the added internal heat from earth is very small, something like $90mW/m^2$. We also know that the surface emits about $390W/m^2$.
According to Kirchoff´s law for blackbodies, if earth is in equilibrium and emit $390W/m^2$  it must absorb $390W/m^2$. With the small addition of $90mW/m^2$.

The fact that the internally generated addition is only $90mW/m^2$ tells us that the solid earth actually IS in equilibrium. It absorbs $390W/m^2$ and it emits the same. So if we would turn off the light, earth would eventually cool of to $90mW/m^2$. Or probably not even that, since the added heat from the sun must be a driver in those internal nuclear reactions. Without an intensity of $780W/m^2$ from the sun (1/2 of area heats the whole sphere), there would probably not be any generation of heat inside.

I don´t know where the idea of "trapped heat" comes from. There is nothing in thermodynamic physics that support such an idea. Gases absorb heat, that is- they get heated. That process can be simplified to $σ(T1^4-T2^4)$ where the atmosphere and surface is either T1 or T2. It gives the rate of transfer, which is transferred heat. In this case "heat" is the only type of energy that raise temperature, no matter if "photons radiate in all direction". A body at higher temperature is not affected by those photons from cold gas. Very basic thermodynamics.

I have read all the litterature I can find, and there is no support for the claim that a gas of mean temperature -18C can raise the temperature of it´s own heat source. The litterature on heat transfer is very clear about that, if two bodies of different temperatures interacts, the only one affected is the colder one. It climbs in energy until it reaches the warmer bodys temperature, and then there is no exchange of heat. This is clear in $σ(T1^4-T2^4)$. 
Everyone makes the assumption that absorption=heat, which is not true. If you put a bowl of ice or cold water in a warm room, it will absorb and emit energy, but no one would claim that it adds energy that raise the temperature. Somehow people think that cold air works the opposite way, because "photons radiate in all directions". All data on co2 shows how it only gets heated, there is no data showing that co2 can raise the temperature of it´s own heat source. Which is natural, because co2 doesn´t add any energy or heat, it only adds heat absorbing mass. Cold heat absorbing mass. The claim that $240W/m^2=390W/m^2$ because of cold air, is very unphysical.
The "effective temperature" of 255K isn´t supposed to be the surface temperature. It is what an isothermal blackbody would radiate from the tropopause from it´s infinitely thin surface that is perfectly black.

Hot Sun->warm earth->cold air->space at 3Kelvin. 
It is very clear which direction the heat is going. It´s like a free fall of energy to space, like a waterfall. One way.

Consider two layers, the surface and atmosphere. $1m^2$ When you add the atmospheres cold air on top of the warm surface, you don´t have $2m^2$, you still have $1m^2$. What you do is mix those twe energy densities into one, which means dilution from the lower energy density of the atmosphere to the energy density radiated from the surface. That is why earth radiate 255K to space instead of 288K.

That was a sidetrack. To get back to your question, I would also like some more information about the relationship between the internal heat and solar radiation, but I don´t think there is any. The above reasoning is from my own understanding of physics and how it "must" be.

Answer (score 2):

The effect of the total mass on the Earth is pretty negligible, so the effect on the Earth as a point mass is also negligible.   There is some change in mass distribution.

The added mass by E=MC^2 is negligible.  CO2 traps heat and heat has mass so an atmosphere that traps heat has more mass than an atmosphere that doesn't, but this effect in minuscule compared to other atmospheric mass changes like the changes from burning fossil fuels, fluctuations in plant and animal life year to year, gas released from volcanic eruptions, variation in atmospheric water vapor and oceanic absorption.

If we go by this estimate, [4 Hiroshima bombs per second](http://www.skepticalscience.com/4-Hiroshima-bombs-worth-of-heat-per-second.html), and 1 Hiroshima bomb has a TNT equivalent of 60 million megajoules, (I'll skip the math), the trapped heat per year added by climate change is currently about the mass equivalent of 90 tons per year, most of that goes into the oceans.  That might sound like a lot, but the earth is hit by almost 200 tons of sunlight per day.   90 tons of added heat per year comes to trapping only a bit more than 1/10th of 1% above the standard equilibrium of equal heat in and out.   The Earth, for comparison, [loses an estimated 95,000 tons](http://scitechdaily.com/earth-loses-50000-tonnes-of-mass-every-year/) of hydrogen and helium every year to the solar wind.   90 tons per year (most of that going into the oceans), is insignificant.

Mass distribution however, is slight less insignificant.

In the atmosphere, CO2 traps heat mostly in the troposphere.   The presence of more CO2 [has a cooling effect in the upper atmosphere](http://www.space.com/18430-global-warming-carbon-dioxide-space-junk.html) so because of man made climate change, the troposphere is expanding and the outer atmosphere is contracting and while most of the mass is in the lower atmosphere, most of the volume is in the upper atmosphere, so the edge of the atmosphere as a whole is moving somewhat closer to earth due to the additional CO2.  This might also cause a slight drop in loss of hydrogen by water vapor being hit by high energy photons, but on that point, I'm just speculating and any variation in lost hydrogen is also insignificant.

The upper oceans expand as they grow warmer, but this expansion is [by this article](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2016/jan/26/sea-level-rise-from-ocean-warming-underestimated-scientists-say), currently about 1.4 mm per year (5.5 inches per century), and while the rate of ocean rise can vary based on the rate of ice melt, the rate of thermal expansion should be fairly consistent, until the new temperature equilibrium is reached when it should level off.  This thermal expansion, however, doesn't have much effect on the Mass distribution.

The biggest effect on mass distribution, by a wide margin is the melting ice caps.  As ice-caps melt, the Earth's mass distribution changes fairly significantly and the Earth rebounds in places to adjust, called [Post-Glacial rebound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-glacial_rebound).  This process is quite slow, so slow, in fact, that parts of the Earth are still rebounding from the last ice age.   But that's the primary effect regarding your question.   Atmospheric temperature changes are irrelevant, Oceanic thermal expansion is mostly irrelevant but melting ice and adding water to the oceans is the biggest effect.   Still pretty small in a practical sense though.

This doesn't much affect anything in orbit.  Satellites in orbit around the Earth's equator aren't much effected because they feel the tug of the entire earth, and the oceans rising maybe a foot in 100 years is largely irrelevant from an orbital perspective.   Where this kind of gravitational variation is most relevant is in plotting what parts of the Earth will get the greatest sea level rise.  An inch or two more here, and inch or two less there.

More specifics and some fun reading here:   https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/melting-glaciers-muck-up-earths-gravitational-field/

Google "changes in the earth's gravitational field due to melting glaciers" and you'll find a number of articles.